# glob() finding images, but echo'ing as missing

Tags: php, glob

Im using glob() to find any image files matching a rule.

I'm using the following code:

```
$photo = glob(($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg'));

print_r(glob(($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg')));
```

Which produces the following:

```
    Array ( [0] => /var/www/web/stocklist/photo/Pituophis deppei jani.jpg 
[1] => /var/www/web/stocklist/photo/Pituophis deppei jani1.jpg )
```

Then when i echo the images to the page using the code below, it displays 2 broken image icons...

```
$length = count($photo);


        if($length) {
        echo"<ul id='slide'>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        echo "<li><img src='".$photo[$i]."' alt='".$row['Name']."'></li>";}

        echo "</ul><ul id='slide-pager'>";

        for($i2 = 1; $i2 < $length+1; $i2++) {
        echo "<li><a href='#".$i2."'>".$i2."</a></li>";

        }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
        else {
        echo "<img src='/stocklist/photo/placeholder.jpg' class='img-right'><br clear='right'>";
        }
```

Comment: You need to remove `/var/www/web` from your image paths. That's a server absolute path, not a web accessible one. Use `str_replace`. Seems though you need to learn about HTTP and web servers first, then PHP.

Comment: str replace is working perfectly. Thanks @Sergiu Parashiv :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
$photo = (glob('stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg'));
print_r(glob('stocklist/photo/'.$row['Scientific'].'*.jpg'));
```

That way your returned paths will already be relative to your public folder. You could also do a str_replace as @sergiu suggested, but why not just get rid of it entirely?